Best orientation of common antenna types relative to whip antenna?
Whip antennas are often described in their datasheets as omnidirectional but despite this, I've often read that when you have two whip antennas communicating with each other, the best orientation is:

I.e. one should arrange them so that the two antennas parallel to each other. As I understand it, the radiation pattern, rather than being a perfect sphere (as it'd need to be to be completely omnidirectional), is donut-shaped with the weakest signal at the two ends (base and tip).
If this is the case, I was wondering what the best orientation of a whip antenna is relative to other common antenna types?
I know every antenna is different and that ideally one would determine the best orientations experimentally or by examining the datasheets of the antennas.
But often I find the datasheet information hard to interpret and just wanted to know what the best expected orientation is for different types relative to a whip antenna. Why relative to a whip? Because I often have setups where I have a base station where space isn't an issue and I can afford to have a large whip antenna (like the ones shown above) and an antenna on some device where space is at a premium and some other antenna type is needed (or already dictated by being part of the device).
E.g. here are some possible orientations of a chip antenna relative to a whip antenna - even if you constrain yourself to just 90° rotations in the x, y and z axes, you get quite a lot of possible orientations. So, I'd just like to know which orientation I should expect to be best.

Here are the common antenna types that I find myself using on one side with a whip antenna on the other side, and for which I'd be interested in the best expected orientations:



Type
Example




Inverted F



Chip (lower right)



Helical



3D




I haven't actually come across the style, that I've labeled 3D above, that often but I just included it as it was used on a board I received recently.
Maybe there's a good guide to the typical radiation pattern for common antenna types such that one can deduce the best orientation but my googling has tended to just turn up very dense technical overviews rather than easy-to-digest general guidelines.

The 3D antenna is an inverted F. A variation of the serpentine PCB one in your first picture.

Antenna distribution patterns are available in the literature.
Whips oriented as you show them are correct with the radiation patterns looking somewhat like t
circular flattened doughnuts so the way you have them shown is correct.
The inverted f transmits to the right with the board flat on a horizontal surface. Its somewhat equivalent to a Yagi antenna. To transmit to a whip  it should be placed on a flat surface pointing at the whip.
The helical antenna is equivalent to a whip but while what you show is common it lacks a proper ground plane and will be much the worst for the lack of it. It will probably help to add a ground plane under the whip over the top of the electronics with a hole through the ground plane for the antenna but isolated from it.
The chip antenna depends on design and you need to look at the data sheet.
I don't know the 3D antenna and it is possible that it is not a formal design although it may be.
If you have an RSSI indicator on any device in the link you can investigate antenna orientation by changing it and watching what the signal strength indication does.
You can get field strength modules from eg China for under $20.
You have not shown sleeve dipoles which have a whip vertically but add  a metal tube extending downward from the base of the whip connected to the coax outer where the whip starts but not connected to the outer or inner at any other point. Sleeve length depends on the coax velocity factor and is typically about 80% of the whip length.
A whip can be placed at the end of a length of coax with the whip vertical and three or more radials as long as the whip connected to the coax outer and extending downward at about 30 degrees.
The angle of the radials affects impedance and  30 degrees is about optimum for matching 50 ohm coax.

Thanks for all the details, Russell. For the inverted-F, when you say it should be "pointing at the whip", I presume you mean the bottom tip of the ꟻ should be pointing at the whip, i.e. "ꟻ↓"? Or perhaps you mean "ꟻ→"?

It’s not the pattern but the polarization. A whip is vertically polarized and will receive best when the signal is vertically polarized. There are also horizontally polarized antennas such as the ones used for over-the-air television reception. There is also circular polarization which comes in left-handed and right-handed varieties and is used for things like satellites where the polarization can be varied during propagation. And there is slant and elliptical which is a mix of a circular and one of the linear types. Maximum signal will be transferred when both receiving and transmitting antenna polarizations are matched.

Thanks for making clear the issue of polarization rather than radiation pattern.

While the other answers are mostly correct, note that a whip is only half of an antenna. The feedline and whatever conductive stuff it's connected to are equally important in establishing the radiation pattern and polarization.
Scattering of radiation by objects in the environment also plays a role. Back, oh, 6 decades ago I experimented with VHF television antennas and found that often I achieved better reception with a vertically polarized Yagi despite the  fact that transmitters use horizontal (probably because I was experimenting near ground level, with lots of matter near or in the line of sight).

Yes re half an antenna. I gave 3 examples re "completing the antenna". The ground plane for the small helical, the sleeve for the whip to make a sleeve dipole, and the ground plane made with 3 angled radials. If I have anything wrong in my answer please advise - I'm happy to correct it.

@RussellMcMahon You mention specific examples, but you don't make it clear that a counterpoise always exists or the antenna won't accept power from the feed. With a whip, it's all the stuff connected to the "ground" side of the feed, whether intentional or not.
